# css horizontal menu with drop-down to vertical menu with drop-down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I would like to change a horizontal menu with a drop-down to a vertical menu with the drop-down items floating on the right or left, as well as all submenus. I am assuming this is an easy fix but I can figure it out. Thanks

Here is a working example of the horizontal working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPMZJV

Here is the CSS:

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

body {
    background: #909eab url(bg.png);
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px;
}

nav {
    margin: 100px auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }


nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }
        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
        }
            nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #fff;
            }

        nav ul li a {
            display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
            color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
        }


    nav ul ul {
        background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
        position: absolute; top: 100%;
    }
        nav ul ul li {
            float: none; 
            border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
        }
            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 15px 40px;
                color: #fff;
            }   
                nav ul ul li a:hover {
                    background: #4b545f;
                }

    nav ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }
```

Here is the html:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>CSS Dropdown Menu</title>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            </ul>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need this on all levels or just the first level?

Comment: All levels. I was hoping to have an "infinite" option, if possible. I am just testing on a few levels for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you'll want to remove your `float: left` from the list-items, set a fixed with for your nav and then change the positioning of the dropdowns to your desired position.

As mentioned in the comments, to get the submenus to align with the menu item the user hovers on, you will need to set it to `position: relative` so that the absolute positioning of the child element is relative to that of the `ul > li` element.

```
nav ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
```

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/MwVvxd)

Comment: Thank you. This is very close. I am looking to have the submenus next to the button they highlight. This way they can just slide the mouse over and the submenu is horizontal to the button just highlighted.

Comment: so for that you would need to set the `<li>` to be position relative so that the submenu's postition is relative to the parent. I have updated my codepen

Comment: You got it. Bam! Thanks so much. You are the MAN. Wait.. no, you are the GUY! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the float of the list items and re-position the second level menu :

```
      nav ul li {
    /*float: left;*/ <<<< removing float left
}

    ....


    Bbackground: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }


nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 30%;left:92%;//<<< setting new position for second ul
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```